# Convert tensor sum to real value

Tags: python, theano

How can I convert the following

```
Sum{acc_dtype=float64}.0
```

to a real value to be able to print it?

I have tried `T.cast`, but it is not working.

Comment: You should explain precisely what "not working" means. What is the expected output? What do you get instead?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to print a tensor variable directly, this will never work, you always have to define computations via [tensor/symbolic](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html) variables and then pass real data/values to them to actually evaluate those computations.
This should work:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

x = T.matrix('x')
sum_0 = T.sum(x, axis=0)
sum_1 = T.sum(x, axis=1)
f0 = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=sum_0)
f1 = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=sum_1)
x_d = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype=theano.config.floatX)
print('x: ', x_d)
print('sum{axis=0}: ', f0(x_d))
print('sum{axis=1}: ', f1(x_d))
```

I would suggest going through the [Theano basic tutorials](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/) and then [Deep Learning tutorials](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/index.html).